# Lie derivative as smooth vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

I was reading Lee's smooth manifold in page 228 when talking about the Lie derivative.

In the **Lemma 9.36**,the proof of $\mathcal{L}_V W$ is a smooth vector field,it seems only the proof that $\mathcal{L}_VW$ is smooth is presented,the proof that it is a vector field is not shown in the book.

We can prove this since the expression satisfy the product rule:

$$(\mathcal{L}_VW)_p = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{d(\theta_{-t})_{\theta_t(p)}(W_{\theta_t(p)}) -W_p}{t}$$ acts on the product function $fg$ correct?

Comment: For each $p$ and $t$, the RHS is a certain vector $\xi_p(t) \in T_pM$. So, if $\lim_{t \to 0}\xi_p(t)$ exists, then the limit is once again an element of the same vector space $T_pM$; which means the final result is still a vector in $T_pM$. There's no need to check if it satisfies the Leibniz rule.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Why the limit in the same vector space?since $T_pM$  is finite dimension so it is closed correct?No notion of norm?

Comment: If you give $T_pM$ a certain norm then yes, because it's a finite-dimensional space it is automatically closed (it's also complete). But in this case, the reason is not even that complicated, the limit lies in the same vector space simply because of the definition of limit. If $f:V\to W$ is a function between normed vector spaces, we say $f$ has a limit at the point $a\in V$ if: $\exists l \in W, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta> 0, \forall x \in V, 0< \lVert x-a\rVert_V < \delta \implies \lVert f(x)-l\rVert_W< \epsilon$.

Comment: Note that it's because of the "$\exists l\in W$", which is the very first thing in definition of limits that limits always lie in the in the same vector space. Imagine if you have a function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^3$, $f(x,y) = (x,y,x+y)$, and I ask you to calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$. You'll obviously say the answer is $(0,0,0)$. How weird would it be if you gave me an answer like $(0,2,0,1,0,0) \in \Bbb{R}^6?$ Or even worse: would you give an answer as an element of some weird vector space like $\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^4, P_3(\Bbb{R}))$? Of course not.

Comment: I see , thank you